# PHP jquery carousel position

Tags: php, jquery, text-files, carousel

I'm using php pagination to load different data from a text file. I am using a jquery carousel http://tympanus.net/Development/Elastislide/index4.html that is featured on each page created from the pagination. What I would like to do is, depending on which page you are on, the carousel will load in a different position. To get this working, I'm thinking I would need to change the jquery which loads on each created page?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#carousel').elastislide({
            imageW      : 110,
            margin      : 20,
            border      : 4,
            easing      : 'easeInBack',
            current     : 12
        });
</script>
```

So if the pagination is on the page.php?p=12, the carousel would be on thumbnail 12? Example html:

```
<div id="carousel" class="es-carousel-wrapper">
    <div class="es-carousel">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="page.php?p=1"><img src="images/img1.jpg" width="100" height="130" alt="image01" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="page.php?p=2"><img src="images/img2.jpg" width="100" height="130" alt="image02" /></a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

the pagination i'm using:

```
<?php
    $data=file("students.txt");
    $pages=0;
    foreach($data as $temp){
        $x=explode("|",$temp);
        if($x[0]>0){
            $pages=$pages+1;
        }
    }
    if($_GET['p']){
        $page=$_GET['p'];
    }
    if($_GET['i']){
        $index=$_GET['i'];
    }  
    if($index == "p"){
        $page=$page-1;
    }
    if($index == "n"){
        $page=$page+1;
    }
    if($page < 1){
        $page=1;
    }
    if($page > $pages){
        $page=$pages;
    } 
    $line=$data[$page-1];
    $fields=explode("|",$line);  
?>
```

I'm new to PHP and I really don't have a clue on how to put this together...

Does anyone have any ideas how to make this work? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have that PHP be the first thing on the page, then in the carousel script initiation block use:

```
current : <?=$page?>
```

or, if you're unsure whether short tags are enabled:

```
current : <?php echo $page;?>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to start from page 12 or depending on your p value, you can do:

```
$('#carousel').elastislide({
            imageW      : 110,
            margin      : 20,
            border      : 4,
            easing      : 'easeInBack',
            start     : <?php echo $_GET['p']; ?>
        });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

In your elastislide call, set the "current" property of the object literal being passed to be the value 12 by pulling it from the url (assuming you're using your example of "page.php?p=12").  Check out [this SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/q/901144/435460) for a pure javascript function on how to get the parameter.  In your example you would use

```
getParameterByName('test')
```

for the "current" property's value.